# How can I vertically align the symbol of items in itemize?

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

I would like to create a list (itemize) with checkboxes such that vertically, the middle of the box should be aligned to the middle of the text.
A MWE is

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\huge$\square$}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

Current result is on the left, while the goal is on the right.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `\raisebox`.

[image: alignment]

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raisebox{-.25\height}{\huge$\square$}}
 \item Item 1
 \item Item 2
 \item Test
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```